# Editing a script using grep and sed

Tags: sed, grep, aix

I work on AIX.
I have a lot of sql files that contains the following string:

```
${DB_USERNAME}.${TABLE_NAME}
```

How could I change it in each file so that it remains only

```
${TABLE_NAME}
```

I have tried following pattern of sed.

```
sed 's/^[^\.]\+\.//'
```

But it returns only ".".

I need to change files directly. As I think we should pipe output of grep to sed. remember I am on AIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n -e "s/^${DB_USERNAME}\.${TABLE_NAME}\$/${TABLE_NAME}/" -e p filename
```

or

```
sed -i -e "s/^${DB_USERNAME}\.${TABLE_NAME}\$/${TABLE_NAME}/" filename
```

to change the file directly.

Comment: `-i` is not a standard option in `sed` and if GNU tools are not install it's very unlikely that it will be supported on AIX